# Manually implementing Regression Likelihood Ratio Test

Tags: r, testing, statistics, linear-regression

I'm trying to implement my own linear regression likelihood ratio test.

The test is where you take the sum of squares of a reduced model and the sum of squares of a full model and compare it to the F statistic.

However, I am having some trouble implementing the function, especially when dealing with dummy variables.

[This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13evSuUw439WwMTMHjp--mLxUip3S1vtQ) is the dataset I am working with and testing the function on.

Here is the code so far:
The function inputs are the setup matrix mat, the response matrix which has just one column, the indices (variables) being test, and the alpha value the test is at.

```
linear_regression_likelihood <- function(mat, response, indices, alpha) {
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)
  reduced <- mat[,c(1, indices)]

  q <- 1 #set q = 1 just to test on data

  p <- dim(mat)[2]
  n <- dim(mat)[1]

  f_stat <- qf(1-alpha, df1 = p-q, df2 = n-(p+1))
  beta_hat_full <- qr.solve(t(mat)%*%mat)%*%t(mat)%*%response
  y_hat_full <- mat%*%beta_hat_full
  SSRes_full <- t(response - y_hat_full)%*%(response-y_hat_full)


  beta_hat_red <- qr.solve(t(reduced)%*%reduced)%*%t(reduced)%*%response
  y_hat_red <- reduced%*%beta_hat_red
  SSRes_red <- t(response - y_hat_red)%*%(response-y_hat_red)



  s_2 <- (t(response - mat%*%beta_hat_full)%*%(response - mat%*%beta_hat_full))/(n-p+1)

  critical_value <- ((SSRes_red - SSRes_full)/(p-q))/s_2
  print(critical_value)
  if (critical_value > f_stat) {
    return ("Reject H0")
  }
  else {
    return ("Fail to Reject H0")
  }
}
```

Here is the setup code, where I setup the matrix in the correct format. Data is the read in CSV file.

```
data <- data[, 2:5]

mat <- data[, 2:4]


response <- data[, 1]


library(ade4)
df <-data.frame(mat$x3)
dummy <- acm.disjonctif(df)
dummy
mat <- cbind(1, mat[1:2], dummy)

linear_regression_likelihood(mat, response, 2:3, 0.05)
```

This is the error I keep getting.

```
Error in solve.default(as.matrix(c)) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.63035e-18
```

I know it has to do with taking the inverse of the matrix after it is multiplied, but the function is unable to do so. I thought it may be due to the dummy variables having too small of values, but I am not sure of any other way to include the dummy variables.

The test I am doing is to check whether the factor variable x3 has any affect on the response y. The actual answer which I verified using the built in functions states that we fail to reject the null hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error originates from line

```
beta_hat_full <- qr.solve(t(mat)%*%mat)%*%t(mat)%*%response
```

If you go through your function step-by-step you will see an error

> Error in qr.solve(t(mat) %*% mat) : singular matrix 'a' in solve

The problem here is that your model matrix does not have full column rank, which translates to your regression coefficients not being unique. This is a result of the way you "dummyfied" `x3`. In order to ensure full rank, you need to remove one dummy column (or manually remove the intercept).

In the following example I remove the `A` column from `dummy` which means that resulting `x3` coefficients measure the effect of a unit-change in `B`, `C`, and `D` *against* `A`.

```
# Read data
data <- read.csv("data_hw5.csv")
data <- data[, 2:5]

# Extract predictor and response data    
mat <- data[, 2:4]
response <- data[, 1]

# Dummify categorical predictor x3
library(ade4)
df <-data.frame(mat$x3)
dummy <- acm.disjonctif(df)
dummy <- dummy[, -1]    # Remove A to have A as baseline
mat <- cbind(1, mat[1:2], dummy)

# Apply linear_regression_likelihood
linear_regression_likelihood(mat, response, 2:3, 0.05);
#          [,1]
#[1,] 8.291975
#[1] "Reject H0"
```

---

### A note

The error could have been avoided if you had used base R's function `model.matrix` which ensures full rank when "dummyfying" categorical variables (`model.matrix` is also implicitly called in `lm` and `glm` to deal with categorical, i.e. `factor` variables).

Take a look at

```
mm <- model.matrix(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = data)
```

which by default omits the first level of `factor` variable `x3`. `mm` is identical to `mat` after (correct) "dummification".